# Upload failed Your APK's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-manifest

Hi i am publishing my android app on google play. But i am getting error 
Upload failed
Your APK's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and underscores (_). It must start with a lowercase character. It must be 150 characters or fewer.

my package name is "com.triviastreak.quiz" 
can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Is Ur package in Ur release APK the same?

Comment: Have you develop android app on native or other like xamarin?

Comment: Most probably its happening in Xamrin. So please Make sure you are using correct format in manifest file like `com.example.myapp`?

Comment: Is this also the packagename that is set in your build.gradle?

Comment: yes this is same in build.gradle

Comment: yes, i m creating release apk with same package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check your version code in Manifest file if this is your new App then it should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine.But try something else like "com.triviastreak.mobile.quiz". It might work. If that doesn't work let me know.